# Makefile compilations problems

Tags: c++, makefile, git-bash

I'm trying to compile my .cpp files with a made makefile but it wont compile. I have 2 directories ex1 and ex2. Help will be appreciated and thanks in advance!

makefile:

```
output: Main.o Gamer.o Manager.o Person.o EncryptionDerived.o
    g++ Main.o Gamer.o Manager.o Person.o EncryptionDerived.o -o output -I.

./Main.o: ./ex1/Main.cpp
    g++ -c ./ex1/Main.cpp

./Gamer.o: ./ex1/Gamer.cpp
    g++ -c ./ex1/Gamer.cpp

./Manager.o: ./ex1/Manager.cpp
    g++ -c ./ex1/Manager.cpp

./Person.o: ./ex1/Person.cpp
    g++ -c ./ex1/Person.cpp
 
./EncryptionDerived.o: ./ex2/EncryptionDerived.cpp
    g++ -c ./ex2/EncryptionDerived.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o output

run:
    ./output
```

and this is what i get from comand line

```
./makefile: line 1: ./Main.o:: No such file or directory
        ./makefile: line 4: ./Gamer.o:: No such file or directory
./makefile: line 7: ./Manager.o:: No such file or directory
./makefile: line 10: ./Person.o:: No such file or directory
./makefile: line 13: ./EncryptionDerived.o:: No such file or directory
./makefile: line 16: clean:: command not found
./makefile: line 19: all:: command not found
./makefile: line 21: output:: command not found
g++.exe: error: Main.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Gamer.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Manager.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: Person.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: error: EncryptionDerived.o: No such file or directory
g++.exe: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
./makefile: line 24: run:: command not found
./makefile: line 25: ./output: No such file or directory
```

Comment: You are asking the *shell* to execute your makefile as a script. But a makefile is not a shell script. Try typing `make`.

Comment: I'm using gitbash to make myself clear I have to write `makefile` into the console and then it should run, right?

Comment: No, you have to write `make` at the console and then it should run.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
output: Main.o Gamer.o Manager.o Person.o EncryptionDerived.o
    g++ Main.o Gamer.o Manager.o Person.o EncryptionDerived.o -o output -I.

Main.o: ex1/Main.cpp
    g++ -c ex1/Main.cpp

Gamer.o: ex1/Gamer.cpp
    g++ -c ex1/Gamer.cpp

Manager.o: ex1/Manager.cpp
    g++ -c ex1/Manager.cpp

Person.o: ex1/Person.cpp
    g++ -c ex1/Person.cpp
 
EncryptionDerived.o: ex2/EncryptionDerived.cpp
    g++ -c ex2/EncryptionDerived.cpp

clean:
    rm -rf *.o output

run:
    ./output
```

Comment: Hi, Same problem unfortunately.

Comment: How are you using your Makefile? With `make -f makefile`?

Comment: No, i just type in ```makefile``` and thats it.